# Constraining one generic with another in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, generic-constraints

I've run into a problem where I have some protocol:

```
protocol Baz {
    func bar<T>(input:T)
}
```

The function `bar` is made generic because I don't want the protocol itself to have a `Self`(it needs to be useable in a collection). I have an implementation of the protocol defined as:

```
class Foo<S>: Baz {
    var value:S

    init(value:S) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func bar<T>(input:T) {
        value = input
    }
}
```

This gives an error because the compiler doesn't know that `S` and `T` are the same type. Ideally I should be able to write something like:

```
    func bar<T where T==S>(input:T) {
        value = input
    }
```

or

```
    func bar<T:S>(input:T) {
        value = input
    }
```

The first form gives a "Same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'S' and 'T' equivalent" error (which is exactly what I'm trying to do, so not sure why it's an error). The second form gives me a "Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'S'".

Any ideas of on either how to get this to work, or a better design pattern in Swift?

**Update**: As @luk2302 pointed out, I forgot to make `Foo` adhere to the `Baz` protocol

Comment: I fear that is not possible: Imagine you add a type constraint on `Baz` - say T has to conform to Hashable. When you want Foo to conform to Baz you cannot implement bar utilizing its generic parameter `S` because there is no guarantee that `S` conforms to `Hashable`as well.

Comment: Hmm... two things: (1) I would think the generic parameter `S` for `bar` is independent on the protocol itself; (2) I agree without some type of type constraint, the compiler cannot know that `S` and `T` are the same types. But what I don't understand is why I couldn't enforce that with constraints.

Comment: You cannot enforce that with constraints because what would happen if you say `T where T==S` and T is simply ***not*** S, what would happen to the method? Your class would no longer conform to the protocol :/

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess I am used to c++ with SFINAE. That is unfortunate, because that means there is no good way avoid making the protocol itself be generic, and doing so forces me to also write type-erasure classes...

Comment: Hmmmm, Swift generics are just not ready for full use yet :(

Comment: @luk2302 I disagree that Swift generics are a problem here. The lack of SFINAE is likely intentional rather than an oversight. The main problem is that protocols with associated types can generate some tedious code, particularly when dealing with collections. It's protocols that have a lot of limitations right now, not generics particularly. The protocol as given is not meaningful and the compiler is complaining about that.

Comment: @RobNapier okay, that is actually kind of what I meant. In the past few days I have come across quite a few problema regarding generics and protocols, maybe a bit harsh to call generics out on that - they simply do not offer all the functionality someone might expect. For example extending a class with a protocol for a given type constraint.

Comment: @AbeSchneider I edited my answer to include a "fix" for the initial example above that gave you an error. However, when "fixes" are needed, most likely another method should be used (--> Robs answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@luk2302 has hinted at much of this in the comments, but just to make it explicit for future searchers.

```
protocol Baz {
    func bar<T>(input:T)
}
```

This protocol is almost certainly useless as written. It is effectively identical to the following protocol (which is also almost completely useless):

```
protocol Baz {
    func bar(input:Any)
}
```

You very likely mean (and hint that you mean):

```
protocol Baz {
    typealias T
    func bar(input: T)
}
```

As you note, this makes the protocol a PAT (protocol with associated type), which means you cannot put it *directly* into a collection. As you note, the usual solution to that, if you really need a collection of them, is a [type eraser](http://robnapier.net/erasure). It would be nice if Swift would automatically write the eraser for you, which it likely will be able to do in the future, and would eliminate the problem. That said, though slightly tedious, writing type erasers is very straightforward.

Now while you cannot put a PAT directly into a collection, you can put a generically-constrained PAT into a collection. So as long as you wrap the collection into a type that constrains T, it's still no problem.

If these become complex, the constraint code can become tedious and very repetitive. This can be improved through a number of techniques, however.

Generic structs with static methods can be used to avoid repeatedly providing constraints on free-functions.

The protocol can be converted into a generic struct (this formalizes the type eraser as the primary type rather than "as needed").

Protocols can be replaced with functions in many cases. For example, given this:

```
protocol Bar {
    typealias T
    func bar(input: T)
}

struct Foo : Bar {
    func bar(input: Int) {}
}
```

You can't do this:

```
 let bars: [Bar] = [Foo()] // error: protocol 'Bar' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

But you can easily do this, which is just as good:

```
let bars = [(Int) -> Void] = [Foo().bar]
```

This is particularly powerful for single-method protocols.

A mix of protocols, generics, and functions is much more powerful than trying to force everything into the protocol box, at least until protocols add a few more missing features to fulfill their promise.

(It would be easier to give specific advice to a specific problem. There is no one answer that solves all issues.)

Comment: I'm creating a `Graph` class with each node adhering to the `GraphModule` protocol. `GraphModule` has two methods: `forward(input:Tensor<StorageType>)` and `backward(input:Tensor<StorageType>, gradOutput:Tensor<StorageType>)`, where `StorageType` is the Protocol's `typealias`. A class implementing `GraphModule` must keep the input modules and output modules (sometimes singular, sometimes a list). Thus I'll often need lines such as: `var toModule:GraphModule`, which of course can't work with PATs.

Comment: (cont'd: Thus, following the standard library, I'll have to create a wrapper class that performs that type erasure or create a closure like you have suggested.)

Comment: Without seeing all the design, I would suspect that `Tensor` doesn't really need to be specialized on `StorageType`. Instead I'm betting `Tensor` could be constructed with `read` and `write` closures passed in. If that is tedious (there are more than one or two methods), then I would first try to just type-erase `StorageType` inside of `Tensor` (rather than creating an `AnyTensor` eraser). That way the type erasers don't spiral out of control.

Comment: The reason `Tensor` has a `StorageType` is for purposes of dispatch (specifically to select native, CUDA, or other for the operations. You are certainly welcome to if you would like (https://github.com/abeschneider/stem), though I'm sure you can find better ways to waste your time :).

Comment: (I happen to be right in the middle of writing a talk about this exact topic. I keep looking for really simple examples to demonstrate it, so if your code is available, I'd love to see it for inspiration.)

Comment: Btw, your blog has been awesome in learning Swift, so thank you for that as well!

Comment: @RobNapier Slightly off-topic, but as I feel I'm out of my depth here (with regard to swift convention) and you are obviously not, I'd be grateful if you could answer the following: is my generic approach below a plain out bad idea (not in the context of this question but in the context of it's use with a typealias / self)? And additionally, unnecessary complex for something that could be made in a simpler way? (Also, thanks for your great blog, I've learned a lot there!)

Comment: If my library is useful at all and have any questions, please feel free to ask! The graph stuff hasn't been committed yet (for obvious reasons).

Comment: This feels similar to some stuff I tried to write in Scala to create a generic multi-strategy solver for discrete optimization problems. I remember drowning in associated types that time too… I'll definitely play with this further.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED** (Workaround for *"... an error because the compiler doesn't know that S and T are the same type."*)

First of all: This is just an separate note (and perhaps an attempt at redemption for my previous answer that ended up being myself chasing my own tail to compute lots and lots of redundant code) in addition to Robs excellent answer.

The following workaround will possibly let your implementation `protocol Foo ...` / `class Bas : Foo ...` mimic the behaviour you initially asked for, in the sense that class method `bar(...)` will know if generics `S` and `T` are actually the same type, while Foo still conforms to the protocol also in the case where `S` is **not** of the same type as `T`.

```
protocol Baz {
    func bar<T>(input:T)
}

class Foo<S>: Baz {
    var value:S

    init(value:S) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func bar<T>(input:T) {
        if input is S {
            value = input as! S
        }
        else {
            print("Incompatible types. Throw...")
        }
    }
}

// ok
var a = Foo(value: 1.0) // Foo<Double>
print(a.value) // 1.0
a.bar(2.0)
print(a.value) // 2.0
let myInt = 1
a.bar(myInt) // Incompatible types. Throw...
print(a.value) // 2.0

// perhaps not a loophole we indended
let myAny : Any = 3.0
a.bar(myAny)
print(a.value) // 3.0
```

The `Any` and `AnyObject` loophole here could be redeemed by creating a dummy type constraint that you extend all types (that you wish for to use the generics) to, however not extending `Any` and `AnyObject`.

```
protocol NotAnyType {}

extension Int : NotAnyType {}
extension Double : NotAnyType {}
extension Optional : NotAnyType {}
    // ...

protocol Baz {
    func bar<T: NotAnyType>(input:T)
}

class Foo<S: NotAnyType>: Baz {
    var value:S

    init(value:S) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func bar<T: NotAnyType>(input:T) {
        if input is S {
            value = input as! S
        }
        else {
            print("Incompatible types. Throw...")
        }
    }
}

// ok
var a = Foo(value: 1.0) // Foo<Double>
   // ...

// no longer a loophole
let myAny : Any = 3.0
a.bar(myAny) // compile time error
let myAnyObject : AnyObject = 3.0
a.bar(myAnyObject) // compile time error
```

This, however, excludes `Any` and `AnyObject` from the generic in full (not only for *"loophole casting"*), which is perhaps not a sought after behaviour.

Comment: The issue is that I'm trying very hard to keep the protocol from having a `Self`, and therefore did not have a  `typealias U` in the original example. If you do that, you solve the immediate problem, but create a a new problem where you can't just keep a collection of that type (due to having a `Self`). For my actual code (not the example given above), I think the only way to solve that is to use type-erasure, which can add a lot of extra code.

Comment: This is unnecessary, and I think creating your troubles: `func bar<T: MyBazType where T == U>(input: T)`. What I believe you mean here is just `func bar(input: U)`. Why declare `T` if it must be `U`?

Comment: For example, this provides the same behaviors you describe without `_MyTypeSeparator`. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/10eb5c220ce15cb50538

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks for the feedback! I was blindly trying to solve the OP statement _"Ideally I should be able to write something like_ `func bar<T where T==S>(input:T) ...`", and by somewhere along the line adding a typealias, I ended up chasing my own tail. Thanks!